# String .replaceAll() unexpected behaviors while getting data from Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, replace

I am wondering with this behavior. In my application I am getting data from server , or my own created database. ( I clone server database)

```
.replaceAll ( "\r\n" , "<br/>" ) ;
```

When the data is come from server that it replace. But When data is get from sqlite database its unable to replace the above. As I have try `.replaceAll ( "a" , "??" ) ;` and its working.

The database data is

> Bradley Ambrose is the freelance cameraman who recorded the John Key and John Banks tea meeting.\r\n\r\nHe intentionally placed a black bag with a recording device on the table where Key and Banks were sitting, although he claims it was a mistake, If that were true then how did so many people get a copy of it???\r\n\r\nAlso this guy bloody changed his name from Brad White what the hell is this guy an international man of mystery or something.

I have also debug that issue in detail. But the is not replaced even code is executed the above line successfully. 
I have also try

```
replaceAll ( "\n" , "<br/>" )
replaceAll ( "\r" , "<br/>" )
```

There is debugging picture. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the input string contain actual CR and LF characters or pairs of \ and r and \ and n?

The regex won't work in latter case. It would require `.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n" , "<br/>")`

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine.  The data you are seeing in the debug screen is wrong.  Do the same debug session and insert a system.out.println and check the output with the output in the debug screen.

Unless you you mean the database actually has the string "\r\n".  The above assumes that the database actually contains the carrige return and line feed characters.  If your database actually has the backslash character followed by the 'n' character then your regex needs a simple tweak. s.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "
")

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with Pattern#quote() ?

Something like:

```
System.out.println("hello\r\n\r\n something".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\r\n"), "
"));
```